# How to add max-width to responsive iframe?

Tags: css, video, iframe, responsive-design

I've cobbled together [this little fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/2nu817d9/) and I'm happy with the visual result. The goal was to make a centered responsive video iframe.

But I've been unable to figure out a good way to add a max-width of 1920px.
If you have a full HD video it would be nice to not let it go any bigger.

And if my CSS can be improved, don't hesitate.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="embed-responsive">
         <iframe width="640" height="360" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/176131682?title=0&byline=0&portrait=0" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
</div>


html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
.container {
    height: 100%;

}
.embed-responsive {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0; right: 0;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -28.1%;
    /* video height / video width */
    padding-bottom: 56.2%;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.embed-responsive iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5%;
    left: 5%;
    width: 90%;
    height: 90%;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can basically keep the properties of your iframe as is, and add the max width to your container. You will need to change its position to relative, and make it a block level element so you can ensure it stays centered. See below:

```
.embed-responsive {
    position: relative;
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    max-width:1920px;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    top: 50%;
    transform:translateY(-50%)
}
.embed-responsive iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 5%;
    width: 90%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/2nu817d9/21/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem that I seem to have when adding "max-width: 1920px" to either "embed-responsive iframe" or "embed-responsive" is that the iframe will no longer be centered.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer @ATomCalledStu. This is what I get when I use your updated css. https://imgur.com/a/mmrEQhm

Comment: @JonnyS No, that is what you get when you add my css to your existing code. You have a negative margin-top applied to your container. Check my updated fiddle, you will see it works fine. Note that i have changed the max width in the fiddle so you can see how it functions

Comment: Yes @ATomCalledStu it worked like a charm. Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

My solution is to add  wrapper around iframe wrapper/parent. This way you dont disturb iframe structure, so iframe wrapper adapts to own parent. I wish it's clear enough : )

```
.wrapper{
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px; //set your `max-width` here
  max-height: auto; //necessary to keep proportion
  margin: 0 auto; //centering 

}
.videoWrapper{
  width:100%;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

iframe{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 0;
}

<div class="wrapper">
        <div class="videoWrapper">
          <iframe src=""></iframe>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: try to explain your code also. Just writing a code won't make others understand that where did they fail, and what is your resolution